# C# return Socket object

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

updated code:

```
public static Socket socketConnect()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Console.WriteLine(sck.Connected.ToString());
                IPEndPoint connectAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8000); // Server IP & PORT 
                sck.Connect(connectAddress);
                Console.WriteLine(sck.Connected.ToString());
                if (sck.Connected == true)
                {
                    return sck
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep time before reconnect
            }


        }
```

how can i use sck outside this method?

for example i want to check in main if sck.Connected is true or false

yes i'm new in c# ..

now im having new problem everytime i want to send or recv i write socketConnect().send or recv and then the program execute the socketConnect() method again but i only want to use sck to send and recv
what im doing wrong?

Comment: return Socket instead void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method to return `Socket`

```
public static Socket socketConnect()
```

and instead `break`

```
return sck;
```

Your sck object is on the heap so it will be still accessable after returning it.

Comment: And do something about the 'while(true)' - statements like that will give you grief, especially when your 'catch' doesn't get you out of the loop.

Comment: I would also recommend to remove the while loop and try catch and let the caller handle it.

Comment: this is client app and i want it to reconnect every amount of seconds so i use the while loop. there is better way?

Comment: `while (true)` is fairly idiomatic when working with networking loops. I don't see it causing any grief and, if the goal really is to try forever, then what other option do you have?

Comment: im having new problem now i want to use sck for send or recv so i need to write socketConnect().send and then it go back and execute the socketConnect() function but i only want to use the sck for send or recv what im doing wrong?

Comment: @user3458842, not sure what you're trying to do, but you could always try to separate the call and the returned object: `Socket s = socketConnect();` and then call `s.Send(...);` in some other place.

Comment: @Nick, say network is down or server at the other end is unavailable then `Socket s = socketConnect();` will hang forever. If the client does not expect it to hang and this call is part of a button-push event handler, then this will freeze your UI. A better way would be to have a timeout value and exit loop after timeout has been reached. The goal is never to really 'try forever'.